# Provide the medical term

Tags: nouns

Is there a **medical term** that defines when a person gets uncontrollably scared during a frightening action, such as on a roller coaster ride when it is going fast and turns a person upside-down and they scream and cry out of control?

Comment: What makes this a medical issue?  Do they have some sort of brain injury or something?

Answer (score 3):

I'd have used the non-medical term *hysteria* for this. Looking at the Wikipedia page for [*hysteria*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteria), it seems the medical term is [*conversion disorder*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_disorder).

Comment: It may not be an anxiety disorder. The [DSM-V](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSM-5) says that only a single instance of mania (even "[subclinical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/subclinical]" [ie, cannot be detected by the usual clinical tests] mania!) is sufficient for assigning a diagnosis of bipolar-II disorder because "there is no such thing as pharmacologically induced mania" (that's the rationale for the change from the DSM-IV), but this is pure nonsense.

Answer (score 3):

It's called **[panic](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/panic)**. The problem here is that it can be caused by something real, like a roller coaster ride, in which case it might be an extreme but not abnormal reaction to an outside stimulus, or by nothing at all, in which case it's a symptom of one kind of *anxiety disorder* or other: [panic disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panic_disorder) is one candidate. Just because someone panics on a roller coaster, however, is no reason to assume that they have *panic disorder*.

Comment: Right. There are symptoms and then there are disorders. The panic the OP is referring to is a symptom that is appropriate for the situation, like having a stuffy nose for a cold as opposed to an allergic reaction.

Comment: For a single occurrence, "panic attack" is appropriate and might be considered a medical expression.

Comment: @gmgath: Yes, you're right. It is, in fact, a medical expression because it is, in fact, **one symptom** of the anxiety disorder called Panic Disorder.